# How to store and use multiple users' keys for third party client

Tags: redis, spotify, credentials

I want to build web app that uses [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/). I got case where user has to authenticate with his spotify account, then I recive **access and refresh token** that is being used in code to authenticate calls to Spotify to perform some actions on user's account.

I have trouble deciding how it should be really done. First thing that came to my mind - store them in Redis for some time, update on refresh and whenever we need to perform some action on any user we get his credentials and do it. Is this proper way? I tough about simply storing them in app memory but I might want to make in serverless.

Did anyone come accross that kind of problem? Do anyone know how to do it 'properly'.